# Redirect sub-domain all post to main domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all posts that are on subdomain to live domain.

For example, www.blog.mydomain1.com/post-1 to www.mydomain1.com/post-1

I try this htaccess code , It redirect the main subdomain but it does not redirect the post links

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mydomain1\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**My Complete HTAccess is**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.(.+)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [NC,R,L]

# BEGIN MainWP
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/mainwp-child/(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/THIS_PLUGIN_DOES_NOT_EXIST [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# END MainWP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.(.+)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this Redirect.

Comment: only www.blog.mydomain1.com rediect to www.mydomain1.com but this post www.blog.mydomain1.com/post-1 not redirect to www.mydomain1.com/post-1

Comment: Are any other links redirecting?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, there are 300+ posts in blog.mydomain1.com.

Comment: @nikunjchavda I think there is something wrong with your currunt htaccess setup, can you post your complet htaccess in the question?

Comment: I have posted blog(subdomain) htaccess. Please check and let me no if any issue. and Thank you so much for try to resolving our issue

Comment: @nikunjchavda Is your htaccess in blog folder or in Root folder?